# How to shade outside a circle in JSXgraph

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, jsxgraph

I'm currently trying to shade inside and outside a circle in JSXgraph, similar to an inequality.

My current code to create a circle:

```
 var A = board.create('point', [h, k], { name: '', size: 0, fixed: true}),
        B = board.create('point', [h, k+r], { name: '', size: 0, fixed: true}),
        graph = board.create('circle', [A, B], { id: field, size: 0, fixed: true });
    graph.on('down', function (e, i) {
        showMaster(this.id);
    });
    graphMap.set(field, graph);
    inequality(">", field, graph, color);
```

I have found that you can shade inside using these object proprieties:

```
{strokeWidth: 2, dash: 2, fillColor: 'red', fillOpacity: 0.3}
```

However, nothing in shading outside.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I was thinking that perhaps put background shaded and inside the circle white, but I have problems with opacity.

Comment: The closest I got from the answer is something like the live example: https://jsfiddle.net/jvn1p54m/ But grid is gone... anyone help?